# Semantic UI React Jsx Attribute modified by state not rendering css class

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Under a JSX attribute (a Semantic UI component), I have listed a state variable that is dependent on the user being on a mobile or browser view as directed by this NPM package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect).

The code for the JSX comes from semantic UI react so that may have something to do with it. I have a specific class for the JSX element to be rendered in a specific way, but the of setting the variable disregards this command. The following code is set in the ComponentDidMount function.

```
if (isBrowser) {
      this.setState({dependentOnView: "small"})
  } else {
    this.setState({dependentOnView: "huge"})
  }
```

The JSX attribute in question is the following.

```
<List divided selection class="specialHighlight" size={this.state.dependentOnView}><List.Item> <Label color='blue' horizontal> Delayed - Theorizing Now</Label> Exchange </List.Item></List>
```

The state is set in the constructor like so,

```
this.state = {
        dependentOnView: ''
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Of course the package is properly imported, like so,

```
import {BrowserView,MobileView,isBrowser,isMobile} from "react-device-detect";
```

The css class in question, is being completely ignored by the after runtime.

```
.specialHighlight {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 65vh;
line-height: 2vh;
font-size: 2vh;
margin-left: 3vw;
```

}

Answer:
This is a very niche case, but setting the size in the List element did nothing, but setting the size of the label in the List Item, which what I was trying to do in the first place, worked. Further, as I was going back in the edits I forgot to use {this.*state*.whateverattribute}.

Further Answer:
Using className as an attribute means that the native semantic UI css will **overwrite** the css you have inputed, therefore in this instance I used class but in most instances the proper way is to indeed use className.

For people looking at the answer in the future:
1. Ensure package is properly imported

2. Ensure Semantic JSX attribute has state properly inputted
3. Ensure state is properly set
4. Try changing the css class setting between *class* and *className*
5. Lastly, try setting other elements with the state variable, it's highly possible for whatever reason semantic won't allow certain variables to be set with certain elements
6. If all else fails, change the native css for semantic UI

Big shoutout to the commentator MikeRos for his input.

Comment: Can you share your CSS or styling code as well? Also, the code for `<List>` components? Looks like you are adding the state data in a `size` attribute instead of `class`, so we would need to see the implementation of `<List>`

Comment: class in JSX is className (common mistake !) ) and we need `<List />` component.

Comment: <List.Item>
      <Label color='blue' horizontal>
      Delayed - Theorizing Now
      </Label>
      Exchange
    </List.Item>

Comment: .specialHighlight {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 65vh;
    line-height: 2vh;
    font-size: 2vh;
    margin-left: 3vw;
  }

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the List component there?

Comment: Are you using Antd `< List />` component? the second part is your import `import {BrowserView,MobileView,isBrowser,isMobile} from "react device-detect";` Should it be `react-device-detect` or `device-detect`?

Comment: I would recommend you to install eslint( https://eslint.org/ ). It help a lot catching those kind of typos

Comment: You are correct, it is react-device-detect but in my project I have it listed as such and for whatever reason it copied over wrong. I will edit the question, thank you for the eslink pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you are using sematic-ui. Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct your 'class' > 'className'

Here is working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brook-r4xio) for you

```
import React from "react";
import { isBrowser } from "react-device-detect";
import { List, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";

class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dependentOnView: "huge"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (isBrowser) this.setState({ dependentOnView: "small" });
  }

  render() {
    const { dependentOnView } = this.state;

    return (
      <List
        divided
        selection
        className="specialHighlight"
        size={`${dependentOnView}`}
      >
        <List.Item>
          <Label color="green" horizontal>
            Delayed - Theorizing Now
          </Label>
        </List.Item>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

Comment: If you could please paste some relevant code here for other users to see. Particularly if you could show some list and list elements that would be very useful. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem Nik .